# Javascript animates both form fields, only want one

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, this

I have a search and a subscribe field.  I want them both to look and feel the same, so I copied the working code from the search field to the subscribe field.  The fields should expand when you click on them, and the value disappears so the user can enter their own.  The only thing is that now when you click on one of the fields, the animation happens to both fields.  I think the problem may be with my understanding of "this" in javascript, but perhaps not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<br />
<form target="_blank" id="subscribe" method="post" action="https://www.myaction.com">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="myusername">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" id="subscribe" onfocus="javascript:if(this.value=='Email Address')this.value='';"   onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Email Address':this.value;" maxlength="100">
</p>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: this.value=!this.value should be this.value!=this.value

Comment: remove javascript protocol from onfocus

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" id="subscribe" onfocus="this.value = this.value ==='Email Address' ? '' : this.value;"   onblur="this.value = this.value || 'Email Address';" maxlength="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being in my HTML.  Stupid mistake.  Thanks for your help.